# How to use orderBy and with in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

How to use `orderBy()` with `with()` relationship where `orderBy` needs column which is being brought in by using `with()`.

**UPDATED**

```
return $rank = BusinessDetails::with(['rar' => function ($query) {
        $query->orderBy('int_total_ratings_value', 'DESC');
    }])
    ->select('pk_int_business_id', 'vchr_business_name', 
    'vchr_business_description', 'fk_int_category_id', 'fk_int_location_id')
    ->get();
```

Business Model

```
<?php

namespace App\BackendModel;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use App\User;
use App\BackendModel\BusinessImages;
use App\BackendModel\Categories;

class BusinessDetails extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    const ACTIVATE = 1;
    const DEACTIVATE = 0;

    public static $days=[
            ['name'=>'Monday','id'=>1],
            ['name'=>'Tuesday','id'=>2],
            ['name'=>'Wednesday','id'=>3],
            ['name'=>'Thursady','id'=>4],
            ['name'=>'Friday','id'=>5],
            ['name'=>'Saturday','id'=>6],
            ['name'=>'Sunday','id'=>7]
        ];

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'pk_int_business_id';
    protected $table = 'tbl_business_details';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'vchr_business_name', 'vchr_business_description', 'vchr_telephone_number', 'vchr_company_mobile_number', 'vchr_company_email', 'vchr_contact_person', 'vchr_logo_path', 'fk_int_category_id', 'date_date_of_establishment', 'vchr_website', 'time_open_hours', 'time_close_hours', 'time_lunch_hours','int_closed_on','int_status', 'int_review_status','fk_int_user_id','fk_int_location_id','vchr_map','vchr_holiday'
    ];


    public function rar()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\BackendModel\OverallRating', 'fk_int_business_id', 'pk_int_business_id')
        ->select('fk_int_business_id', 'float_overall_ratings' , 'int_no_of_ratings', 'int_total_ratings_value', 'int_no_of_reviews', 'int_no_of_like');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a closure to the `with()` and apply order by there.

Here is an example

```
Model::with(['relation' => function($query){
   $query->orderBy('column', 'ASC');
}]);
```

Updated

```
return $rank = BusinessDetails::with(['rar' => function ($query) {
        $query->orderBy('rar.int_total_ratings_value', 'DESC');
    }])
    ->select('pk_int_business_id', 'vchr_business_name', 
    'vchr_business_description', 'fk_int_category_id', 'fk_int_location_id')
    ->get();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: no change in the order of records

Comment: post your code what you are trying to do

Comment: updated please check

Comment: @Jigs1212   $query->orderBy('rar.int_total_ratings_value', 'DESC'); try this

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column

Comment: @Jigs1212 'tableName.int_total_ratings_value try like this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166866/discussion-between-jigs1212-and-laravel-levaral).

Comment: @laravel-levaral

how do i use another variable inside the function ($query)